# What is preventing us to start using scrypt in production ?

Tags: passwords, secure-coding

After a lot of reading the expert opinion on password hashing, I understand that scrypt (which is both memory hard and CPU intensive) is a good candidate for password hashing. But I saw the experts recommending a wait of at least 5 years until it is thoroughly peer reviewed and baked (chicken and egg problem ? :) )

- In 2015, can we take the plunge and start using scrypt with confidence ?
- Is there a plan to make this a standard / recommendation by NIST and other standard bodies ?

[ref 1](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage/6415#6415%00)

[ref 2](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/about-secure-password-hashing/)

Comment: I dont see how this is a question. I doubt anyone **can** answer explicitly yes or no... You should rephrase this to ask a question vs start a discussion.

Comment: @Matthew Peters Do you have any suggestions ? I intend to know if it is safe / secure to use scrypt in a production environment in 2015 or should I hold off until NIST / any other standards body approves ?

Comment: Maybe something like: "What is preventing us to start using scrypt in production"?

Comment: The point is to wait for the results of review, not simply to bide your time until a 5 year clock runs out.

Comment: Also discussed in [this thread](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/65663/12).  I don't think anyone's jumping at the bit to make SCrypt the standard choice for password storage.

Comment: Got additional insights from this wonderful answer by @Thomas Pornin on another question - http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5605/are-there-more-modern-password-hashing-methods-than-bcrypt-and-scrypt?rq=1 - Short answer - bcrypt for *now*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If we want to look for rational reasons *not* to use scrypt right now, we can find mostly these three:

- It is unclear whether a "memory-hard" function is what is needed, with the parameter configurations supported by scrypt. Scrypt was initially designed to support local encryption, particularly whole-system encryption. This means that the password must be hashed during the system bootup process; at that time, the computer has nothing else to do, so the whole CPU and RAM is available for a single scrypt; and since bootup already takes a non-negligible amount of time, a password hashing extending over 5 or 10 seconds is no hardship.

  A typical server will need a distinct configuration, that uses less RAM (a server cannot afford a gigabyte per password hashing, if it has to serve several clients and not crumble under peak load) and less CPU (a Web site authentication should be done within less than 1 second, because users are not patient; and, there again, we must account for peak load). Whether scrypt is better than bcrypt when configured for "server usage" remains to be seen; in fact, if you need to put CPU usage down to about 1 ms per hash, then scrypt uses *less* RAM than bcrypt, making the latter a superior option.
- As far as memory hardness is concerned, scrypt turned out not to be as optimal as it could be. Some GPU-based optimization is still doable with time-memory trade-offs. The attacker's gain is not devastating, but if we are to change our password hashing function then we may as well try to find one that fulfils its promises.

Such issues, and other information, can be found in [this presentation](http://www.openwall.com/presentations/Passwords12-The-Future-Of-Hashing/). To summarize: while the ideas expressed in the scrypt design are quite interesting, the general feeling of cryptographers is that there should be more research; and, indeed, it prompted the [PHC](https://password-hashing.net/): an open competition, in the spirit of past efforts such as AES, SHA-3 or eSTREAM, where new candidates are proposed and reviewed.

If you deploy scrypt right now in production, then it *should* be reasonably strong, although it depends on the parameters you choose. *That* is the main conclusion of 5 years of research: the cryptography is sound, there is a time-memory trade-off which is not damning, *but* we don't have a lot of guidance on how to configure it in ways that will work well in typical servers.